# Wann ist es angebracht, obligatorisch und verboten, ein zusätzliches »es« einzufügen?

Tags: subordinate-clause, clauses

Könnte ich Folgendes ändern?

> Mein Traum für die Zukunft **ist es**, mich in ein paar Jahren
>   selbstständig zu machen und meine eigene Firma zu gründen.

zu :

> Mein Traum für die Zukunft **ist** mich in ein paar Jahren
>   selbstständig zu machen und meine eigene Firma zu gründen.

Meine unbestätigte, Vermutung: Infinitivkonstruktion erfordern "es".

Comment: Solange du das Komma wieder einfügst, ist beides in Ordnung.

Comment: _ist_ schreibt sich klein.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nein. Wörter schreiben *sich* nicht selbst irgendwie. Die muss *man* schreiben. Auch wichtig: Das erste Wort in einem Satz muss man immer groß schreiben. Daher ist richtig: »*Ist* schreibt **man** klein.« - Wenn du das Wort, dessen Kleinschreibung du verlangst, auch in deiner Aufforderung klein schreiben willst, darf es nicht das erste Wort im Satz sein. Besser wäre also: »Das Wort *ist* schreibt man klein.«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wie Du meinst :-D ...

Comment: Similar: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27195/use-of-es-to-anticipate-a-following-clause/